# Passing a Taxonomy term via URL to add content form in Drupal 7

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, uri

OK, I have a Drupal 7 site.  And the scenario is that, let's say I'm on a page of my site that happens to have a taxonomy term assigned to it - let's say it's term ABC.  Well in a block in the sidebar I have a link that sends the user to the ADD CONTENT form for a Forum Topic.  The Form Topic content type has a CCK field as well (same vocab).  I'm trying to automatically populate that field with the same term ABC as the page that they came from.

I was thinking this could be passed via URL as a GET parameter, but not sure if that would work and if so how to pull it off exactly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the module [Prepopulate](http://drupal.org/project/prepopulate) ; latest release is dev but I use it on a production site and it works like a charm.

If it doesn't work tell me, there are two other solutions : send an arg in the URL to the form (and then use Panels or the php template) and JavaScript (I can give you the code if you need it).

Answer (score 0):

You would use Views, and a contextual Filter. Taxonomy Term: Term ID. Then provide the value of the T.I.D.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand.  I'm trying to send the person to a create content form, not a view.  Is there something I'm missing?  Is there some way to combine those two actions?